# python How to get value(amount and number) from text file

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry for bothering, I am currently doing my foundation programming project and I wonder if we can get specific value from
text file.
For example:

When I search "Product A":

```
Txt File:   $   amount
Product A: 30 x 20
Product B: 27 x 10
Product C: 24 x 5
Product D: 21 x 80
Product A: 30 x 50
```

It will shows me (expected result):

```
Product A = 70 #amount
Total= $450    #price*amount
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. and is easy once you become aware of all the data structures of python. it can be easily done using a dictionary (a python data structure)

Comment: Excuse me, do you have any example? I am so blur right now. I would like to finish my programming project as fast as I can because there are 4 assignment waiting for me :(
Thank you for giving reply to my question.

Comment: Please provide the text file and the final output you expect. I'll try to code it and guide you how to do it.

Comment: Sure I will do it now, thank you for helping me!!!!!

Comment: Alright, I have edited my question. I have put the content of text file and the output that I expected. If you can't solve this question, it is totally fine because I am already very happy when someone would like to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the required code.

```
file1 = open('data.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
my_dictionary = {}

product = input("Enter the product you want to search: e.g. A, B, C, D :\t").upper()

for line in Lines: # Reading file line by line
    line = line.split()   # spliting the line: ['Product', 'A:', '30', 'x', '20']
    if line[1].strip(':') == product:
        cost = int(line[2]) # Getting the cost of product

    if line[1].strip(':') in my_dictionary: # Checking if product already exists
        my_dictionary[line[1].strip(':')] = my_dictionary[line[1].strip(':')] + int(line[2]) * int(line[4])
    else: # Adding new product to my_dictionary
        my_dictionary[line[1].strip(':')] = int(line[2]) * int(line[4])

try: # Checking of the input product is valid
    print("Product", product, " = ", int(my_dictionary[product]/cost))
    print("Total =", my_dictionary[product])
except: # Handling all invalid cases
    print("Product not found!")

"""
data.txt file -
Product A: 30 x 20
Product B: 27 x 10
Product C: 24 x 5
Product D: 21 x 80
Product A: 30 x 50



OUTPUT -
Enter the product you want to search: e.g. A, B, C, D : a
Product A  =  70
Total = 2100

Enter the product you want to search: e.g. A, B, C, D : b
Product B  =  10
Total = 270

Enter the product you want to search: e.g. A, B, C, D : c
Product C  =  5
Total = 120

Enter the product you want to search: e.g. A, B, C, D : d
Product D  =  80
Total = 1680

Enter the product you want to search: e.g. A, B, C, D : e
Product not found!
"""
```

Comment: Omg it's working. You are absolute a genius. I have stuck at this step for few days already. I never thought that I can get the answer from here. Thank you so much, I hope you are safe and healthy from the bottom of my heart!!!!

Comment: Sorry excuse me again, how should I change the code if the product is no more Product A,B,C ...... Maybe it can become candy or any item. Or is it possible to search the item with the product name instead of A,B,C?

Comment: instead of A,B,C you can write anything. But it should be of type `Product CANDY: 12 x 45`